# Constructing a gray colorscale in d3.js

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to construct a custom colorscale in d3.js. My scale looks like this:

```
       var color = d3.scale.linear()
            .domain([ext[0], ext[1]])
            .range(["#d1d1d1", "#000000"]);
```

Values in the domain are : 500, 35676000

But when i'm calling the color it doesn't choose anything in between the color range.

```
                .attr('fill', function(d, i){
                    return color(i);
                })
```

Comment: `i` is the index, you should pass `d` as the parameter to the `color` function: `color(d)`

Comment: thanks, however it seems the scale is not working properly. All elements get filled #000000

Comment: Are you sure the value of `d` is in the domain when calling the `color`function? You can try to call `color(500)` and `color(35676000)` to check if the problem is in your color function or your data.

Comment: Exactly, I was calling the wrong data in the color function. Thanks for your help. I understand how it works now!